# Sequence of await functions call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

i'd like to know how can i beautify a code snippet in javascript, which Looks like that

```
async sequenceOfFunctionCalls () {
   await callFunction1();
   await callFunction2();
   ...
   await callFunctionN(); 
}
```

Comment: pack the functions in an array and run a async await map on them perhaps?

Comment: with promiseAll you cannot use the previous async response and a pass it to the other

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to run them in sequence (not in parallel), I'd say the simplest option is:

```
for (let func of [callFunction1, callFunction2, ..., callFunctionN]) {
    await func();
}
```

To run them in parallel:

```
await Promise.all([callFunction1, callFunction2, ..., callFunctionN].map(f => f()));
```

or

```
await Promise.allSettled([callFunction1, callFunction2, ..., callFunctionN].map(f => f()));
```